# doctrine odm set random value generated by js Math.random() on pre persist

Tags: mongodb, random, doctrine-odm

i'm trying to implement this pattern http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/random-attribute/ in doctrine odm.

i would like to set this attribute on the pre-persist lifecycle event. To achieve the best results, i would like to use a native javascript function Math.random() because php cannot generate random floats and i would like to avoid writing a custom function for that.

is there a way to achieve this?

i tried:

```
    /** @PrePersist */
    public function generateRandom()
    {
        $this->random = new \MongoCode('Math.random()');
    }
```

but it always sets the attribute to 1, no matter the code of the function

Comment: What type of field is random mapped as?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure that it's best solution but, it works for me:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\PrePersist()
 * @MongoDB\PreUpdate()
 */
public function generateRandom() {
    $this->random = rand();
}
```